# How to limit the number of collection in Firestore query?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to create a query to copy the collections under a document to another path in the Firestore DB.

The thing is, my document contains 60,000 collections inside - so the query I'm running takes forever (if it succeeded).

Assuming this is the query I'm running right now:

```
firestoreCol.doc('docName')
.listCollections()
  .then(cols => { ... });
```

Is there a way to divide the query somehow to make it more efficient?

Comment: I would imagine you want to create 60,000 documents instead of 60,000 collections if it's nested within a collection already? Are you sure you meant to create collections? Would you mind providing your use case so we can help optimize performance?

Comment: FYI on Stack Overflow, backticks are used to mark bits of code, not for emphasis of text.

Comment: @DougStevenson Given the call to `listCollections`, I am not convinced it is just about the performance of *document* retrieval.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I suspect you meant to @ Dan instead?

Comment: Yup. My bad, your name was right above the comment. :)

Comment: @DanFein I meant collections. This is a given database and I cannot change that fact.

As I wrote to the answer of FrankvanPuffelen, it is not about optimization, since firestore queries fail or freezes with this amount of collections, and there is no limit option in the query as it seems to be.

Answer (score 3):

There is no switch that makes the retrieval of the data go faster. The only things you can do to get a result faster, is to use a faster connection, or to retrieve less data.

For example: it is fairly uncommon to have to process data from 60,000 collections. In fact, it is sort of an anti-pattern to perform such broad read operations from most NoSQL databases. More common is to store the aggregated data in the database, and update it on every write operation. That way you're only reading a small subset of the data for every update.

If you have the need to do custom aggregations regularly over all the data, Cloud Firestore may not be the best fit for your requirements. In that case, consider using a solution that is more focussed on dynamic querying, such as BigQuery.

Comment: You mentioned "or to retrieve less data" - this is part of the question... How can I retrieve less data? I couldn't find a way to limit the collections query.

It is not only about time consumption - those queries not always works (it freeze or crash).

Comment: This case is in a given database, I cannot change the structure - I just need to go over 60,000 collections in a single document (possibly more).